# Could not find a method

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

have a strange event. I have two phones 4.1.2 and 2.3.6 android versions, 4.1.2 works fine but older one throws this error.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageButton 

    android:id="@+id/IB_Nearest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="IB_Nearest"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/marker"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    />     
    <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/IB_Category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="IB_Category"
    android:src="@drawable/book"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    />
<ImageButton 

    android:id="@+id/IB_Map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="IB_Map"
    android:layout_below="@id/IB_Category"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mappp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    />

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/IB_Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="IB_Search"
    android:src="@drawable/search"
    android:layout_below="@id/IB_Nearest"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    />
<ImageButton 

    android:id="@+id/IB_NewPlace"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="IB_NewPlace"
    android:layout_below="@id/IB_Search"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/info"
    android:background="@null"

    />

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/IB_Statistics"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="IB_Statistics"
    android:src="@drawable/chart"
    android:layout_below="@id/IB_Map"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void IB_Map (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void IB_Category(View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TreeChoice.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void IB_Nearest (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NearPlaces.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void IB_Search (View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Search.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void IB_NewPlace (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewPlace.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void IB_Statistics (View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Statistics.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    public class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(
            android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

But if I use this listener implementation:

```
final ImageButton rightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IB_Map);
rightButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Everything works, could someone explain why this happens?

```
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method IB_Map(View) in the activity class lt.whitegroup.workplaces.ui.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'IB_Map'
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2131)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.ClassCache.getDeclaredPublicMethods(ClassCache.java:153)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.ClassCache.getMethodsRecursive(ClassCache.java:216)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethods(ClassCache.java:175)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.ClassCache.getMethods(ClassCache.java:167)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:961)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2124)
12-10 00:05:21.875: E/AndroidRuntime(28537):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Phones work fine, tested with two 2,3,6 devices

Comment: What version of FragmentActivity are you using?

Comment: @CarlAnderson good question, how to know?

Comment: in your MainActivity.java file, look at your imports at the top and find the line that imports FragmentActivity.

Comment: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Comment: I was thinking that if you weren't using the support version (you are) that that could be the source of your problem here, but in this case faradaj is probably on the right track.

Comment: To repeat a question is not good.  To do it in a few minutes is just plain wrong.

Comment: Sorry for double post thought that I posted it wrong, because search did not show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `setContentView(R.layout.<your_layout_id>)` in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick

Comment: Removed, but still the same, I also reinstalled the app

Comment: now my method looks like this: `public void IB_Map (){
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
   startActivity(intent);
  }`

Comment: Which android version are you targeting?

Comment: I updated the answer. My previous comment was wrong, my bad. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry my mistake :/ I really sorry, but I was trying to save post readers time and cut out some of code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` always where there

Comment: Probably this is unsolvable, it is good that I can use that other onclick implementation. And this one should have something with fragment activity. But don't know what :)